# Different placeID gives the same address information

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Below two placeID's gives the same address.
1.  EicyMDEgU291dGggTG93cnkgU3RyZWV0LCBTbXlybmEsIFROLCBVU0EiMRIvChQKEgm7_A4lPAxkiBEptR2cpqTb1xDJASoUChIJT4MxvQIMZIgRENDVZ6XiGTc
2.  ChIJBbYyJDwMZIgR1TtBueaig5w

PlaceID1 was returned when the address searched using the autocomplete was " 201 South Lowry Street" and PlaceID2 was returned when the address searched using the autocomplete was " Goodwill Industries of Middle Tennessee 201 South Lowry Street".

Even though the above addresses are different, the place details API gives the same address information.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=EicyMDEgU291dGggTG93cnkgU3RyZWV0LCBTbXlybmEsIFROLCBVU0EiMRIvChQKEgm7_A4lPAxkiBEptR2cpqTb1xDJASoUChIJT4MxvQIMZIgRENDVZ6XiGTc&key=API_KEY

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJBbYyJDwMZIgR1TtBueaig5w&key=API_KEY

Question : 
1.  Why is the same address which is of the street returned for two different placeID's?
2.  The location returned by places Details API is correct but the address is of the street.

Below are few more examples where I observed same scenarios. Could you please brief on the below mentioned examples also?

1. PlaceID : ChIJZ2fZgcNVZIgRRY-uzGW9IBc and ChIJi15Hp8RVZIgRojWuKm_aG3M returned the same address as "2008 Memorial Boulevard Springfield Tennessee United States 37172", but the straight line distance between the two places is approximately 154 meters.
2. PlaceID : EiBBbm5leCBBdmVudWUsIE5hc2h2aWxsZSwgVE4sIFVTQSIuKiwKFAoSCd8ldk-TYWSIEZbufa-nQvmSEhQKEgk9kOsTMuxkiBGg2umh0Lk_fQ and ChIJ9ynrOIthZIgR-_7_cmwzeXo returned the same address as "3736, Annex Avenue Nashville Tennessee 37209" , but the straight line distance between the two places is approximately 6.92 meters.
3. PlaceID : ChIJTZvXpuJ7ZIgR8GqA7eDu5oY and ChIJ3ZUKweJ7ZIgRBjj8OqdMm5E returned the same address as "1777, Galleria Boulevard Franklin Tennessee 37067 " , but the straight line distance between the two places is approximately 12.24 meters.
4. PlaceID : EicyMDEgU291dGggTG93cnkgU3RyZWV0LCBTbXlybmEsIFROLCBVU0EiMRIvChQKEgm7_A4lPAxkiBEptR2cpqTb1xDJASoUChIJT4MxvQIMZIgRENDVZ6XiGTc and ChIJBbYyJDwMZIgR1TtBueaig5w returned the same address as "201 S Lowry St, Smyrna, TN 37167, United States " , but the straight line distance between the two places is approximately 97 meters.

Comment: There is no guarantee that a placeId will be unique (you can have multiple placeIds that return the same place).  Your example, one will be the placeId of the business (Goodwill Industries), the other the placeId of the address.  Those are two different things/places (the business might move, the address won't (probably)).

Comment: Thank you for you response. I have added few more examples. It will be helpful if I get additional information on those examples as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that it's possible for each place or feature to have similar addresses. This is why the Places API used Place IDs instead to uniquely identify the place/feature. As per this [doc](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id):

> Place IDs uniquely identify a place in the Google Places database and
>   on Google Maps.

Below is my investigation on the addresses you have mentioned:

1. The place ID, ChIJZ2fZgcNVZIgRRY-uzGW9IBc, is of type, `premise`. As per the Address Types doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types):

> Premise indicates a named location, usually a building or collection
>   of buildings with a common name.

If you think that a collection of building should not have the same address as the Place ID, ChIJi15Hp8RVZIgRojWuKm_aG3M, then I suggest that you report this Maps Data issue. *(I'll put some more details on how to report Maps Data issues below)*

2. The address returned for EiBBbm5leCBBdmV...iBGg2umh0Lk_fQ is an address of a route (Annex Ave, Nashville, TN 37209, USA), which is not the same as the the second Place ID's (ChIJ9ynrOIthZIgR-_7_cmwzeXo) address (3734 Annex Ave, Nashville, TN 37209, USA).
3. For the Item #3, what I can see is that the place ChIJTZvXpuJ7ZIgR8GqA7eDu5oY is a `street_address` while the other feature (ChIJ3ZUKweJ7ZIgRBjj8OqdMm5E) is a `point_of_interest`. These two features does not seem to be related so I believe that this is another Maps Data issue which can also be reported.
4. The feature, EicyMDEgU29...ENDVZ6XiGTc, on the other hand appears to be an inferred street address from a range of addresses. While the place, ChIJBbYyJDwMZIgR1TtBueaig5w, is the actual point_of_interest that's on that same street address. Note that the point of interest may close or move to a new location, but, the street address most likely won't change.

> For Maps Data issues, this can be reported using the "Report a
>   Problem" or "Send feedback" link on the bottom right corner on
>   [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com) or in the Google Maps for Mobile Application. To learn
>   more, please see this [guide](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088). But for Maps Data that are added
>   using [Google My Business](https://developers.google.com/my-business/), this can be modified directly by the
>   business owners themselves on their Google My Business account.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi annkylah, Thank you for your response. We do have multiple instances of above mentioned issue where in the same address are returned for two different place types. Can you please suggest how we can fix that or if there is any other solution.

Comment: As stated in my answer, Google Maps Data issues are usually reported on the Google Maps consumer app (maps.google.com). To edit information for a place, you can suggest an edit by following this guide (https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7084895). But if a location is missing, yous should follow this guide instead (https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846).