# Cities missing in Google Maps API distance matrix

Tags: api, google-maps, maps, distance, google-distancematrix-api

I have been using the Google Maps API's distance matrix. However, this seems to not be working for some cities and I'd need your help to figure out why / what I'm doing wrong.

Here's what I'm typing to find the distance between Paris (France) and Amsterdam (NL) in train:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?destinations=Paris&language=en-EN&mode=transit&transit_mode=train&origins=Amsterdam&key=XXX`

I've replaced my API key by XXX on purpose here.

Here's what I'm getting in return:

```
\<DistanceMatrixResponse\>

    \<status\>OK\</status\>

    \<origin_address/\>

    \<destination_address\>Paris, France\</destination_address\>

    \<row\>

        \<element\>

            \<status\>NOT_FOUND\</status\>

        \</element\>

    \</row\>

\</DistanceMatrixResponse\>
```

For some reason the <origin_address/> is blank and I can't figure out why.

Thanks :)

Comment: Your request, on my side, with a valid API key, works as expected, when I specify a valid [language code](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport).

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. Did you properly encode the URL (as specified in the official docs)? How are you sending the request? etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Amsterdam (by itself) can't (currently) be found.

Amsterdam, Netherlands (assuming that is what you are looking for) can.

Seems like a data issue.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?destinations=Paris&language=en-EN&mode=transit&transit_mode=train&origins=Amsterdam,Netherlands&key=MY_API_KEY
```

returns:

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<origin_address>Amsterdam, Netherlands</origin_address>
<destination_address>Paris, France</destination_address>
<row>
<element>
<status>OK</status>
<duration>
<value>12000</value>
<text>3 hours 20 mins</text>
</duration>
<distance>
<value>525025</value>
<text>525 km</text>
</distance>
</element>
</row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

Comment: Why is that? And why does it work for me by specifying only *Amsterdam* as the origin? I get the exact same response. Also the language code is wrong, if I use `en-EN` I get results in French, not in English (probably based on my location / browser language).

Comment: As I said in my answer, seems like a data problem.  I get no response from the geocoder for "Amsterdam" by itself, and I _don't_ get the same response if I reverse origin/destination.  None of the "errors" in the URL effect that.

Comment: I do get a proper response from the geocoder for "Amsterdam" by itself, and I do get a very similar response if I reverse origin/destination (I get 3 hours 19 mins when reversed, which doesn't surprise me since the travel mode is transit). The language error does not affect that, I just mentioned it for clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! Do you know if there is a way to flag that so it can be resolved? I've had the same issue with a couple well known cities...

Comment: [bugs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/support), [data issues](https://support.google.com/maps/workflow/12206808) (although it does seem to be on the map...), the answer to the question: [Different placeID gives the same address information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710404/different-placeid-gives-the-same-address-information) has an explanation of reporting data issues as well.